# Getting "You have started editing this post. Abandon this edit?" when saving an edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits

There seems to be a bug.

After I posted, many more posted similar

The most detailed so far is

["Save edits" after editing my answer asks if I want to abandon the edit; Saving a question asks if I want to leave the page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415237/save-edits-after-editing-my-answer-asks-if-i-want-to-abandon-the-edit-saving)

---

I get this in questions and answers.

Latest Chrome on the latest macOS and windows.

Even here at meta I get this.

[image]

Comment: I also noticed that like 10min ago while editing a question here on SO-meta. Certainly didn't happen a few hours prior. I am on Chrome too, though windows 10 (for work ;))

Comment: Yep, seeing it on Firefox as well for nearly every edit over the last 10-15 minutes, across multiple different posts. Clicking "OK" actually accepts the edit and reloads the page. Clicking "cancel" deletes the post body from the DOM, until you refresh, where you see that your edit was actually accepted and applied successfully.

Comment: My guess is someone introduced a confirmation "are you sure" modal to edit submission and accidentally reused the "abandon edit" modal content (or if there was already a confirmation modal, just accidentally replaced it with the "abandon edit" one's content).

Comment: Also saw it on Firefox 95.0.2 on Linux.

Comment: Faced similar issue 5-10 minutes back, even the answer text was erased while editing one of my answers. However refreshing the page gets everything alright along with the edits using updated _Google Chrome_.

Comment: Came here to post this, confused the heck out of me too.

Comment: I've been seeing this, too.  Using Firefox 95.0.2 on Windows

Comment: The result could be something [like this](https://pmortensen.eu/temp2/SO_EditMessedUp_2022-01-11T212015Z0.png) (but not after a refresh). It seems to have straighten itself out by now, though. Or not. At least not here.

Comment: Happening on Chrome 96.0.4664.110, what was odd is the contribution was edited, regardless of the choice.  The only difference was that the normal notification (edited 9 mins ago) didn't appear until a page refresh. Another difference is the content "disappears" but the edit still happens.

Comment: @PeterMortensen that's an interest set of free-hand shapes you've drawn there...

Comment: same on the sqa site.  i thought i nwas losing it

Comment: Also reported on MSE: [Editing a post leads to a weird behavior](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/375054/289905).

Comment: There is even more faulty behaviour, described in detail in my question, which unfortunately got closed as a duplicate of this: ["Save edits" after editing my answer asks if I want to abandon the edit; Saving a question asks if I want to leave the page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415237/save-edits-after-editing-my-answer-asks-if-i-want-to-abandon-the-edit-saving?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Absolutely a bug. No matter which option you pick in the message box, the edit goes through. Then you won't see the post at all after edits, just white space with votes next to it. Then refresh the page and it works. Yay for beta testing before release...?

Comment: Thanks for notifying us, we were able to reproduce it and will try to fix this asap. We'll keep you posted on this question.

Comment: This is going to get annoying fast... It's certainly going to take the wind out of my sails for doing edits until this is fixed...

Comment: @Larnu just hit refresh, the edit takes hold anyway. Mobile SO doesn't have a problem

Comment: @Lundin *Yay for beta testing before release...?* - "let he who has never sinned cast the first stone"

Comment: @CaiusJard it's still poor a UX and annoying.

Comment: Btw, it's not only on meta. Just saying, in case that was the assumption from this post. *(Some come with a bag of stones. But when there's to much wind it'll hurt when they are blown back)*

Comment: @CaiusJard Touché, but I wish the devs would stop treating the main flagship site containing their most important product as their private test server. This is a new phenomenon, in past years they would roll out new features and changes to meta first, or somewhere else where potential bugs are less disruptive and harmful.

Comment: It's not just [so], @Lundin, it appears to be across all communities. On the report on [meta.se] there are comments that it has also been reported on [math.se] and [rpg.se].

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all: thanks a lot to everybody for notifying us about this issue. We have been able to reproduce and fix the issue. Please do let us know (in a comment to this answer) if you're still encountering any issues with this.

Comment: Any details you can share with us on what went wrong here? Did a function call get replaced with the wrong one or something? An event listener that went haywire?

Comment: We are working on extending the navigation prevention alert to work on more scenarios. In this case we suffered a regression.