# "Save edits" after editing my answer asks if I want to abandon the edit; Saving a question asks if I want to leave the page

Tags: bug

This was tested on Safari 15.2 and [macOS 12.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey) on a [M1 Max MacBook Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#5th_generation_(M1_Pro_and_M1_Max)); as per [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/getting-you-have-started-editing-this-post-abandon-this-edit-when-saving-an), other browsers and even [mobile browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375054/editing-a-post-leads-to-a-weird-behavior) seem affected, too.

When I try to edit an answer I've given and I'm done editing, I click the blue "Save edits" button below my answer, as per usual.

Doing so gives me a "You have started editing this post. Abandon this edit?" dialog. If I click **OK** my edits are saved. If I click cancel my answer seems to be completely empty, but after reloading the page it's back.

Please note that this behaviour does not occur if I haven't actually made any changes.

This is highly irritating. What's going on?

[image]

Even when I was trying to ask this question, after clicking on **Review your question** and doing so I went on to **Ask question**, and it gave me this "Do you really want to leave the page?" dialog:

[image]

The question if I want to abandon the edit also occurs on editing this question, not only on editing answers:

[image]

If in that "Abandon edits?" dialog I chose **Cancel**, the resulting page I get looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @Laurel Seems to be the same issue, but I'm also pointing out additional, probably related issues not mentioned in that question. Also I'm describing it in more detail.

Comment: To all voting to close: My question also describes faulty behaviour that is probably *related* to the duplicate issue, **but not mentioned therein**. My question also includes the bug that occurs when trying to ask a question.

Comment: This should be designated dupe target. Much more info here

Comment: @mplungjan We *could* reverse it, and close yours as a dupe of this one, but the devs have chosen to communicate via your question.

Comment: I have moved the link to this up in my question