# Can you (mod?) help me recover my question?

Tags: bug

**Issue was resolved by reloading**

---

Original question:

I wrote this question:
[What is the minimum number of floating-point operations needed to get a one-cent error when computing monetary values with double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70668507/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-floating-point-operations-needed-to-get-a-one-cent/70672146#70672146)

I then edited it to clarify the question based on a response.

I got a message asking, "Are you sure you want to discard this question"?  I hit "cancel" and my question -- and the edit link -- disappeared.

I still have the tab opened in my browser as it thinks I have unsaved work that it warns me of if I navigate away.

Is it possible to recover my question text?

---

Following the link shows I can still edit and see my question text. So I think this is a fairly low-stakes bug that can simply be ignored. Refreshing the page resolved it.

Comment: There's a [known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375054/461068) with the edit functionality, but it doesn't actually stop people's edits from being saved. As you've now noticed, your edit was still saved successfully.

Comment: To recover the question: refresh the page.

Comment: By the way, this is supposed to have been fixed. If you're experiencing the bug then either a) you need to flush your browser cache b) the bug is still somehow present.

Comment: "Is it possible to recover my question text?" - Refresh the page.

Comment: @VLAZ: Yes refreshing the page solved it. But didn't I edit my Q to say that before your response? I wonder where the message was lots. Perhaps yet another refresh issue? :-)

Answer (score 2):

This phenomenon was the result of the issue [Getting "You have started editing this post. Abandon this edit?" when saving an edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415234/getting-you-have-started-editing-this-post-abandon-this-edit-when-saving-an) which is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Hence it should have been solved at your end too.